# MVC4 Enable framework logs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, log4net

Is there a way to enable additional logs from .Net frameworks?

For example I have a strange problem with `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` that I think will be easily solved with some additional info on what the membership provider tries to do.

I'm using log4net(I can change it, if required)

Similar to java, where you can enable the Spring framework logging by adding `log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL` 
to log4j.properties

Answer (score 1):

For exception logging i far prefer the almost automated [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) over the manual do it yourself log4net. Give it a try! It can be easily installed [via nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ELMAH)

Comment: I already have log4net, but I can only log from my code. My question is if I can access the framework logs. I want to know what happens under the hood.

Comment: I don't believe there is much by the way of built in MVC logging apart from Health Monitoring http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/2010/07/28/logging-in-mvc-part-2-health-monitoring/ which may provide some insight for your ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider